# WinAPI SetWindowPos not working for simple apps like notepad and calc

Tags: c#, winapi, setwindowpos, movewindow

I develop on Windows 10.

I want to move and resize an external application. I tried to make it work first with notepad and calculator. But, whatever I do the notepad/cal do not move or resize. I tried using `SetWindowPos`, `UpdateWindow` and `MoveWindow` but nothing worked. I debugged the code, and the inner part of the `foreach` does get executed.

I tried to run it as admin as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24796509/winapi-movewindow-function-not-working-for-some-windows), but it didn't help.

```
static void foo()
{    
    foreach (var p in Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => p.ProcessName.ToLower().Contains("calculatorapp")))
    {
        SetWindowPos(p.Handle, HWND.TopMost, 10, 10, 100, 300, (uint)(SWP.SHOWWINDOW));
        int err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

        UpdateWindow(p.Handle);
        //SetWindowPos(p.Handle, 0, 0, 250, 250, true);
        MoveWindow(p.Handle, 0, 0, 250, 250, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need a window handle, not a process handle.  Like Process.MainWindowHandle provides.  Won't work for calc in Win10 and notepad in Win11, they are now UWP apps.
 Use System.Windows.Automation instead.

Answer (score -1):

Just as Hans Passant said, you need a window handle like this.

```
HWND hwnd=(HWND)0x0xxxxxx;
```

I used SPY++ here to get the window handle of notepad. Then used`Setwindowpos` to move the notepad to a new location and get the new size.
[image]

Comment: @theateist hello, any ideas about this answer?